# Magento Cron will not execute. Invalid Callback error

Tags: magento-1.7, error, cron

I cannot get my custom module to recognize my model.

### AM/Cron/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <modules>
                <AM_Cron>
                        <version>0.1.5</version>
                </AM_Cron>
        </modules>

        <global>
          <models>
                <AM_Cron>
                        <class>AM_Cron_Model</class> 
                </AM_Cron> 
          </models>

        </global>

        <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <AM_cron>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>AM_Cron/checklockedurls::run</model></run>
            </AM_cron>
        </jobs>
        </crontab>
</config>
```

### AM/Cron/model/Checklockedurls.php

```
<?php
class AM_Cron_Model_checklockedurls
{ 
    public function run()
    {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does the error say when you run `getModel('AM_cron/checkLockedURLS')->run()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

To

```
<global>
  <models>
    <cron>
        <class>AM_Cron_Model</class> 
    </cron> 
  </models>
```

From

```
<global>
  <models>
    <AM_cron>
        <class>AM_Cron_checkLockedURLS</class> 
    </AM_cron> 
  </models>
```

Comment: I tried this to no avail. I have updated my original post with my latest code as I am getting the same error after trying @Amit's recommendation.

Comment: Change this to class AM_Cron_Model_Checklockedurls

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of issue in config.xml

Issue1: Model class is not define.As per magento structure Basic model prefix define Model folder not up it class file
:

Just Like :

```
YourModuleNamespace>YourModuleName>Model>
```

thus basic model prefix is

```
 YourModuleNamespace_YourModuleName_Model
```

So.

from

```
<global>
  <models>
    <AM_cron>
        <class>AM_Cron_checkLockedURLS</class> 
    </AM_cron> 
  </models>
</global>
```

to

```
<global>
  <models>
    <AM_cron>
    <!-- change here  -->
        <class>AM_Cron_Model</class> 
    </AM_cron> 
  </models>
</global>
```

**issue2:** you model file name  `checkLockedURLS.php` is wrong  it should be `Checklockeurl.php`.

As Magento logic  `names of files/folders` after Model folder  should be `first letter is start with upper` and `then rest of name is lower letter`

As you define `AM_cron/checkLockedURLS::run` in cron model

magento is split this like this

`Check` folder  `Locked` > file `Urls.php`

That means magento give class for  `AM_cron/checkLockedURLS::run`  is

```
AM_Cron_Model_Check_Locked_Urls and it not match with you code
```

So change :

**checkLockedURLS.php** to **Checklockedurls.php**

then

```
AM_cron/checklockedURLS::run
```

to

```
AM_cron/checklockedurls::run
```

**Config.xml as should name is config.xml**

Comment: Thanks Amit, I have updated my original post with all of your changes but I am still getting the same error. Can you see where I may have goofed in your instructions?

Comment: I'm not sure if mix case will cause an issue see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547151/is-it-possible-to-use-camelcase-class-names-in-magento-models

Answer (score 0):

The directory "model" should have been "Model". After *believing* that I had double, triple quadruple checked cases, spelling, etc.. this slipped past me.

For my original post, the solutions provided did indeed help, but they would not take until I capitalized the Model directory.